# git config shows 2 attributes with same name - does the latter one override the former?

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm running into some performance issues with SmartGit vs command line git, so I thought it may be due to different git configuration.  When I listed my git configuration, I was surprised to see some configuration values in duplicate:

```
$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/dev/tools/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
credential.helper=manager
core.autocrlf=false
user.name=Eric Benzacar
user.email=eric.b@ama.org
http.sslverify=false
gc.autodetach=false
```

In this list, I see `core.autocrlf` listed twice - once on line 2 and once on line 13.

I have intentionally set `core.autocrlf=false` in my git global config, and there is nothing in my .git folder (in fact, I'm running `git config -l` from my root directory to see the above list).

```
$ git config --global -l
core.autocrlf=false
user.name=Eric B
user.email=eric.b@ama.org
http.sslverify=false
gc.autodetach=false
```

I suspect that `core.autocrlf=true` is the git default, although I can find nothing in the git docs (https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) that indicate that this is the case.  Furthermore, I'm confused by both lines.  Does the latter override the former?  Why does Git show both config options?

Comment: They are from different levels. Gitconfig has three levels, system, global and local. Global overrides system and local overrides global. Read the manual of `git config` for more details.

Comment: I closed as duplicate, since the accepted answer describes the override process as well.

Comment: @Torek - Thanks; I looked through SO originally but I guess I missed that post.  That explains exactly what I needed.

Comment: @EricB. It's easy enough to miss since the *form* of the question is quite different.